# Swagger not Showing Example Value

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, swagger-ui

I have spring boot application and Iám traying to add Swagger UI now it's working fine with me but the ***Example Value*** is empty as attached
[image]

I trayed many ways but nothing work with me
the pom.xml

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

and swaggerConfig :-

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.java.SpringCodegen", date = "2023-05-03T07:15:10.757811352Z[GMT]")
@Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc //NOTE: Only needed in a non-springboot application
    @EnableSwagger2
    @ComponentScan("xx.xx.xx.xx.controllers")
    public class SwaggerConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    
    @Bean
    public Docket customImplementation(){

           return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                    .select()
                    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("xx.xx.xx.sews"))
                    .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                    .build()
                    .directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class, java.sql.Date.class)
                    .directModelSubstitute(OffsetDateTime.class, java.util.Date.class)
                    .pathMapping("/")
//                          .enableUrlTemplating(true)
                    .useDefaultResponseMessages(true)
                    .forCodeGeneration(false)
                    .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                    .globalOperationParameters(Collections.singletonList(new ParameterBuilder()
                          .name("x-request-id")
                          .modelRef(new ModelRef("string"))
                          .parameterType("header")
                          .required(false)
                          .build()));
    }

    @Bean
    UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
      return UiConfigurationBuilder.builder() 
          .deepLinking(true)
          .displayOperationId(false)
          .defaultModelsExpandDepth(1)
          .defaultModelExpandDepth(1)
          .defaultModelRendering(ModelRendering.EXAMPLE)
          .displayRequestDuration(false)
          .docExpansion(DocExpansion.NONE)
          .filter(false)
          .maxDisplayedTags(null)
          .operationsSorter(OperationsSorter.ALPHA)
          .showExtensions(false)
          .showCommonExtensions(false)
          .tagsSorter(TagsSorter.ALPHA)
          .supportedSubmitMethods(UiConfiguration.Constants.DEFAULT_SUBMIT_METHODS)
          .validatorUrl(null)
          .build();
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfo(
                "My REST API", //title
                "Some custom description of API.", //description
                "Version 1.0", //version
                "Terms of service", //terms of service URL
                new Contact("Bhanuka Dissanayake", "www.example.com", "myeaddress@company.com"),
                "License of API", "API license URL", Collections.emptyList()); // contact info
    }
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
          .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
          .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver defaultViewResolver() {
      return new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    }
    @Bean
    public static BeanPostProcessor springfoxHandlerProviderBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new BeanPostProcessor() {

            @Override
            public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
                if (bean instanceof WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider || bean instanceof WebFluxRequestHandlerProvider) {
                    customizeSpringfoxHandlerMappings(getHandlerMappings(bean));
                }
                return bean;
            }

            private <T extends RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping> void customizeSpringfoxHandlerMappings(List<T> mappings) {
                List<T> copy = mappings.stream()
                    .filter(mapping -> mapping.getPatternParser() == null)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
                mappings.clear();
                mappings.addAll(copy);
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            private List<RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping> getHandlerMappings(Object bean) {
                try {
                    Field field = ReflectionUtils.findRequiredField(bean.getClass(), "handlerMappings");
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    return (List<RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping>) field.get(bean);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                }
            }
        };
    }
  
    
    
}
```

and my controller

```
@PostMapping("/save-employee")
    @Authorized
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> saveEmployee
    (@Valid @RequestBody Employee obj)
    {
        CustomResponse response = dbService.saveEmployeeAndConvert(obj);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Please help how I can show example value from the models in the application.
to open swagger using ***http://localhost:8080/myapp-ws/swagger-ui/#/***